# How to separately configure application server and web server using tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat, server

I want my application to run on server configured on a different machine how can I do it please help??

my application connects with the database so for security reasons I want to separate both application and server machine

I am using tomcat for server

and I have built a maven java project

right now y projects run on tomcat installed in the same machine but I want to separate my app and server

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve.
Maybe you want to run the Database Server on a diffrerent machine, than the Application + Tomcat Server ? When you build and deploy a Web-Application than it might have Tomcat as Requirement to run.

Comment: 1. I have a database server
2. I have an application that connects with database via some port

Comment: So you basically want to seperate your webApp from the Tomcat Server ?
Did you Use any web related APIs in your App ? like served webpages or maybe a Rest Interface ?

Comment: yes I have used spring and i have installed xampp server in my web server

Comment: I assume you have build a webapp that's more or less a servlet container.
You can find a pretty good description about the Webserver and the Servlet Container on this page: https://dzone.com/articles/what-servlet-container

You might find out, that your app relies on a Webserver (depends on your configuration + code). So that the Servlet will not be able to run / function properly without a (tomcat) Webserver. Since Tomcat is very flexible you could actually embed Tomcat as a dependency and build a single Jar File, that you can deploy on other machines.

Comment: this whole setup is called web, app, db when you host an API or web application from a secured server like banking where you have different layers and each layer is secured by firewall then your database can be hosted in the most bottom(secured) layer then above your db you can develop your application and finally you can do hosting of your application in the DMZ in that way you can assure security of your db which contain most valuable information